# JAVA - Constructor definido pero me pone que no lo tengo definido

Tags: java, constructor

[image: Constructor de la clase]

Como se ve en la imágen tengo creado el constructor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aquí se ve el problema que me marca diciendo que el constructor no está definido pero lo tengo definido en el package beans y si lo intento añadir el paquete beans.Caja; me sale fallo que lo tengo que borrar por que es un import inusable. Nose por que puede ser espero vuestra ayuda. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Me parece que tienes el objeto instanciado. ¿Qué tal si pones datosCaja=null antes de volver a llamar al constructor?

Comment: No hay problemas en reasignar un valor a una variable, a no ser que esta esté declarada como `final`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si te das cuenta tienes dos clases llamadas `Caja`. Una en el paquete `beans` y otra en el paquete `modelo`, siendo esta última donde tienes el problema, el cual está originado porque que el constructor que llamas el compilador lo interpreta como de la propia clase puesto que su nombre es `Caja` y no como el de la que quieres. Para solventar este problema debes utilizar el ***fully-qualified class name*** de la clase que se encuentra en el paquete `beans`:

```
beans.Caja datoCaja;
datoCaja = new beans.Caja(...);
```

PD: Asegúrate siempre de agregar el código como texto puesto que evita que tengamos que transcribirlo para probarlo, en caso de ser necesario, y para compartirte las mejoras hechas sobre este.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias estas en lo cierto, llevaba como 3 horas atascado en esto y no me habia dado cuenta. Mil gracias de verdad

Comment: Un placer ayudarte. Saludos!